# twitter bootstrap popover with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Popovers do not seem to be working for me at the moment.  I'm using the twitter-bootstrap gem for other functions successfully (like the carousel), and can see that tooltip and popovers are loaded in the page's source:

```
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is my javascript (which I placed in application.js)

```
$(function () {
    $('.popover-test').popover({ html : true });
});
```

Here is my what is in my view:

```
<%= link_to('Popover test', '#', :class => "popover-test", :title => "This is a test", "data-content" => "<b>hello popover world</b>") %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You're not initialising the popover. Try:

```
$(function () {
  $('.popover-test').popover({ 
    html : true
  }).popover('show');
});
```

Note the `.popover('show')`

I'd also recommend taking the content logic out of your html so your final result looks like:

```
$(function () {
  $('.popover-test').popover({ 
    html : true,
    title: "This is a test",
    content: "<b>hello popover world</b>"
  }).popover('show');
});
```

...much cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Try this markup:

```
<%= link_to('Popover test', '#', :class => "popover-test", :rel => "popover", :title => "This is a test", :"data-content" => "<b>hello popover world</b>") %>
```

You were just missing the :rel value, and "data-content" should be a symbol.

Comment: hmmm...doesn't seem to be working for some reason.  I still just get the "this is a test" alt text to show up and it's not in the appearance of a popover.

Comment: Try removing the `html: true` option (so it should read `$('.popover-test').popover();` ) - I'm not really sure what that option is, since it's not in the documentation, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Also make sure that you're including bootstrap-transitions in your layout so the popover will fade in and out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this working?  If not, what wisew said is correct, however, he has a small typo -> remove the quotes around "data-content":

```
<%= link_to('Popover test', '#', :class => "popover-test", :rel => "popover", :title => "This is a test", :data-content => "<b>hello popover world</b>") %>
```

See if that does it

Comment: `:data-content` isn't a valid symbol because of the hyphen - it needs to be in quotes: `:'data-symbol'`.